# Different ways to try catch in c#

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I had this block of code:

```
try
 {
// DO SOMETHING
 }
catch (Exception e)
 {  
    throw new WebPartPageUserException("YEAH MESSAGE");
}
```

and the compiler send me a Warning for not using the var e.

Then I change to

```
try
{
 // DO SOMETHING
}
catch (Exception)
{  
     throw new WebPartPageUserException("YEAH MESSAGE");
}
```

And it was ok, but finally I learn that

```
try
{
    // DO SOMETHING
}
   catch 
{  
   throw new WebPartPageUserException("YEAH MESSAGE");
}
```

works too.

Are these 3 blocks doing the same? In that case, which is the best practice?

Comment: Ok, I recognize that should be a better question if I had written  "Different ways to try catch in c# if doesn't care about the exception details" Thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are doing the same and they are **all** bad practice, because you catch *all* exceptions, without even logging the exception details. It will be impossible to know the real cause for your `WebPartPageUserException`.

Comment: +1 plus you are throwing a new exception which loses that stack and are not even including the original exception

Comment: The new exception isn't a problem, granted you add the old exception as the InnerException ofc. I agree that not doing so is wrong.

Comment: @F.B.: I never said that the new exception is a problem. The problem is, that he discards the old exception. Please be more careful when reading.

Comment: @Daniel: I down voted, because catching `Exception` is not a bad practice as long as you rethrow it or throw a more specific exception (which is what is going on here). Of course, were possible, you should catch the most specific exception possible. Also, you can't say that the OP should log the exception, because you don't know at what level in the application this code is written. Logging should almost always be left to the upper most layer in the application. What the OP is doing wrong however, is that he doesn't wrap the inner exception, thus leaving out very useful exception information.

Comment: @Steven: He was asking about several different ways to write is catch block **without** using his exception. That's what my post answers. I never said that catching all exceptions was bad in all cases - I sometimes do it myself - I said it was bad practice, because he is discarding the old exception. Maybe I could have used a better word than logging, when I really meant "use somehow". Your answer however doesn't really refer to his question and the different ways of catching an exception without using it. In conclusion, I wholeheartedly disagree with your downvote and find it cheap...

Comment: @Steven: Especially, without leaving a comment, explaining the downvote. I am tempted to downvote your answer, but really, that would be just as childish.

Comment: @Daniel: My apologies. I have slightly misinterpreted your answer. If bad practice refers to discarding the old exception, than I agree with your answer (except for the logging part). I'm sorry for not commenting directly, but I was planning to explain my downvote, as I always do.

Answer (score 2):

It is dependent on what you want. `catch` alone will catch any kind of Exception. So yes, it's the same as `catch (Exception)`. Sometimes you want to catch special exceptions in a different way. Like a `NullReferenceException`, so you have to specify that. If you want the exception as a variable, you can say `catch (NullReferenceException e)` and then say: `e.StackTrace()` or something similar.

So, in this case, it's the same, but there are ways that it won't be the same.

I agree on the bad practice of @Daniel, but sometimes it's wanted.

*Update*
If you catch an exception and throw a new one, you could set the catched exception as an innerException of your new one

Answer (score 2):

You should do this:

```
try
{
    // DO SOMETHING
}
catch (Exception ex)
{  
    throw new WebPartPageUserException("YEAH MESSAGE", ex);
}
```

Note the use of `ex` as inner exception argument in the `WebPartPageUserException`. Not supplying the inner exception means you're leaving out valuable information about the actual error. You should almost always include the inner exception.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno about best practice but personally I stay away from generic "catch all" try catch block... Try to code such that you test for a scenario that would cause an exception and make the code flow as appropriate to deal with the error case.

Answer (score 1):

`catch (Exception)` only catches Exceptions of Type `Exception` or inherited from that. `catch` catches all Exceptions.

Since most (all?) Exceptions are inherited from `Exception`, #2 and #3 will do the same. For Best Practice, only catch those Exceptions that you can handle gracefully. (You should account for all Exceptions that your try-Block can throw, or at least try to ^^)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to use the Exception reference at all, use the last option. The second option, as written, catches only exceptions derived from "Exception" or subclasses. Using this style of exception handling is useful if you want to distinguish between different kinds of exceptions, but aren't going to use the exception reference. Example:

```
try
{
     DoSomething();
}
catch (NotSupportedException)
{
     Console.Error.WriteLine("The software won't do what you wanted it to");
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
     Console.Error.WriteLine("A possible programming error in the software?");
}
```

You probably should be using the exception references however, if only to store them in a log so that you can get an insight into why the program is failing.